# Install CakePHP from cakephp-3.0.0.zip

Tags: php, cakephp, installation

Just started with **CakePHP** this evening. This is running me out of time.

All I have is a **WAMP Server** on a **Windows7 Machine**.

```
Apache Version : 2.4.9
PHP Version    : 5.5.12
```

Downloaded the latest version `cakephp-3.0.0.zip` from [github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags).

Extracted it to `D: ... wamp/`

As stated here:

> In both XAMPP and WAMP, mcrypt and mbstring extensions are working by
>   default.
>
> In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to uncomment
>   extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the
>   XAMPP Control Panel.
>
> In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working.
>   To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default)
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like
>   icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory
>   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and
>   it should be OK.

On the **httpd.conf**, I have:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restarted the WAMP server and still leading it to directory browsing.

I was looking for a solution from an hour ago. Nothing help as I wanted it it **CakePHP3.0**.

Please help me get the rid outta this.

Comment: Have you followed the composer installation instructions here? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

Comment: I have already installed composer. 
Now when I run `php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_cake-php_app_name` form within my downloads, it took some  minutes, downloading and installing..completed. What next?

Comment: Did you run the composer install within WAMP www folder? Your cake app should go there, then hit it using localhost. Alternatively, have you tried using the built in server by executing `bin/cake server` within the app directory?

Comment: Looking some one to explain the cakephp 3 installation clearly. Like with composer and with out composer. Its pretty tough for newbies

Comment: Followed complete instruction and Installed composure as per given instruction: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html. But unable to link between wampserver and cakephp. Although after running the command C:\wamp64\www\myapp\bin>cake server -H 127.0.0.1 -p 81; I'm able to see cakephp view page at localhost port 81. Need solution to link wampserver and cakephp. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

TO install CakePHP follow instructions below.

Please ensure following things are enabled and installed on your machine.

1. You must have PHP 5.4.16 or above installed on your machine.
2. mbstring extension and intl extension must be enabled to install CakePHP 3 on your machine.

Next Install Composer. For windows users it's very easy just download installer file from composer site.

Here is the .exe installer link to download [Composer-Setup.exe](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)

Once YOu installed composer successfully then run following command in terminal window.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app cquiz
```

[image]

Finally it will ask you to set permission for temp folder, so press Y to continue. it will set writable permission for temp and it's sub folders, also generate security salt for you.

I have given step by step installation instructions for CakePHP 3  here

http://www.smarttutorials.net/install-cakephp-3-using-composer/

Comment: Not working in wampserver, example on given url is just with XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

## Install cakephp 3

1. Installcomposer
2. Run a command explained in below video
3. cakephp 3 installed

You can find complete detail in this video, here I have explained step by step and it will help you to install cakephp 3.
[Video : Install cakephp 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_6OUNg78YE)

Comment: It would be better when you eplain the commands in your answer and not in a video, in case the video is not reachable.